# why doesn't Hibernate generate primary key for many-to-many relationship table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a simple many-to-many tables. One Term can belong to multiple Categories, and one Category can be assigned to multiple Terms.

Term.java

```
@Entity
public class Term implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="terms")
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

Category.java

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<>();

   // getters and setters
}
```

However, the generated intersection table "" doesn't contain a primary key, as seen from here:

```
MariaDB [wordDS]>describe Category_Term;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| categories_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| terms_id      | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Shouldn't a Composite Key always be needed as a primary key, and should automatically created by Hibernate? How can I get that created automatically?

Comment: Why would the join table need a key?

Comment: Without a key, duplicates will be allowed in the table, which normally should be avoided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `Set` instead of a `List` to enforce uniqueness. Hibernate will generate the primary key.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="terms")
private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();

/* ... */

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<Term> terms = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: If it's set, will the insertion order of entries to tables not be preserved as in the input data? I actually want to keep that order, since it's easier to do sanity check in the tables.

Comment: I think if you use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet`, insertion order should be preserved in the table. Haven't tried though. On the other hand, mapping back from the table to the `Set`, I don't think you'll get the same order. As far as I know, Hibernate's `PersistentSet` just wraps around `HashSet`.

Comment: Is Set normally used for associative table implementation? I am quite new to database design.

Comment: I don't know about "normally". IMO, It's the logical choice if you want to enforce uniqueness in a collection.

Comment: "Normally", I mean in most cases, you don't want to store duplicate rows into table. Right?

Comment: I have not yet encountered a use case that would require me to store duplicate rows.

Comment: So, HashSet or LinkedHashSet is better?

Comment: It's not about better or worse, it depends on your use case. For your use case, it seems that `LinkedHashSet` is the preferred choice.

Comment: So, you mean you don't care too much about the order in the table? For debugging, and print out, if you know the order, it's much better. For example, you want to print out all students from a database, and those students are placed into database in some order, and certainly you most likely want to print out in the same order. Right?

Comment: Records in a database table are by definition unordered. If you want ordering, you have to enforce that yourself, using some sort of key. This key can be an auto-incremented ID, a timestamp that indicates insertion time, or something else entirely.

Comment: If use timestamp, do I need to add another column to record the insertion time for each row? Also, I am wondering all records may be inserted into tables instantly at one time, so you may not really know the time difference in insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `List` to a `Set`. This way Hibernate will generate primary keys for the join table.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

for Book entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Book_Author", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Author_Id",nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Book_Id", nullable = false) })
Set<Author> getAuthors(){
..................
}
```

for Author entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "authors")
Set<Author> getBooks(){
..................
}
```

And its generate in postgre:

```
create table book_author
(
    bus_id integer not null
        constraint fks1cidrw188x56mfa802xfj23j
            references book,
    equipment_id integer not null
        constraint fkm0ll4he65a8gfasp0sqg5tp2l
            references author,
    constraint book_author_pkey
        primary key (author_id, book_id)
)
;
```

So, primary key is generated for the two columns together.